# How to delete records from table where timestamp field < now()-44 minute?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to delete records from table where timestamp field < now()-44 minute ?

Comment: Remove a few words from the text you've posted and it's basically correct...

Comment: Mr E means to tell you it's as simple as `DELETE FROM a_table WHERE timestamp_field < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - '44 minutes'::interval)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM table
    WHERE timestamp_field < current_timestamp - interval '44' minute;
```

Comment: I know we're all used to it by now, but it's amazing how many other dbs don't understand basic date math.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE timestamp < DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL -44 MINUTE)
```

Modify for your db of choice.